# Blender exporter for threejs producing invalid file

Tags: javascript, json, three.js, blender

I have a simple model in Blender:

[image]

When I use the [threejs exporter](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender) in blender 2.7 the json file is full of null or 0 values:

```
{
    "metadata": {
        "formatVersion" : 3.1,
        "generatedBy"   : "Blender 2.7 Exporter",
        "vertices"      : 0,
        "faces"         : 0,
        "normals"       : 0,
        "colors"        : 0,
        "uvs"           : [],
        "materials"     : 0,
        "morphTargets"  : 0,
        "bones"         : 0
    },
        "scale" : 1.000000,
        "vertices" : [],
        "faces"    : [],
        "uvs"      : [],
        "normals"  : [],
        "skinIndices"  : [],
        "skinWeights"  : [],
        "morphTargets" : [],
        "bones"      : [],
        "animations" : [],
        "colors"    : [],
        "materials" : [
        ]
}
```

Was going to log an issue on the github page but thought I would bring it up here in case it is user error. Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I worked it out... It turns out that `curves` will not be exported.

As it turns out, I needed to convert each `curve` to a `mesh` mesh with `option + c` (`alt + c` on windows).

[image: the convert function]

File is exporting as expected now.